# PHP - How to workaround SMTP email slowness when attaching files and not force user to wait?

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm developing a "document delivery system" for my enterprise.
It consists on user sending several docs through a form, and backend (PHPmailer) sends it through email (attached) for the correct people.

The problem is that sending the email is too slow (about 1.30min ~ 3min);

Then user would wait for sending files to server (alright, here), and then wait again for server sending it through email.

How can I solve that?

PS: I know I could zip the files and send only a download link via email, but I wanted to keep a backup of those files on the email. Any tips?

Comment: How are you getting these files?

Comment: send in the background, no need for the user to hang around after pressing the send button

Comment: @MosesSchwartz user send them via html normal page, it's stored on the server via AJAX and then sent via PHPmailer

Comment: @tim how do I do that? Like, upload finishes, files are on a folder on server, script will call phpmailer......? Now what?

Comment: exec("php mailer.php $data-or-not > /dev/null &");

Comment: @tim Only two questions more:

1- What "> /dev/null &" means? 
2- What if an error ocurr with mailer.php, like, I reached my email quota, how will I know since nothing is printed to user?
Both questions are related, I guess

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: @Maycow Moura Take a look to mail queue, that  helps me a lot in this type of things, What it does it place a mail in queue and send it to recipient in background .

Comment: Send via a local mail server - get that to do the waiting, queuing, redelivery and bounce processing. Mail servers are built to do this, don't try to get PHP to do it - once you've sent a message using PHPMailer, don't do any more in PHP. You can handle queues using databases or dedicated queue systems (like beanstalkd) and do all your sending asynchronously, so you never need to make a user wait for a page to load (other than upload time).